# data.table reorder columns by index

Tags: r, data.table

**I have**:

```
> aDT <- data.table(col5 = 5, col1 = 1, col2 = 2, col4 = 4, col3 = 3)
> aDT
   col5 col1 col2 col4 col3
1:    5    1    2    4    3
```

as well as:

```
index1 <- c(5,1,2)
index2 <- c(4,3)
```

**I need**:

```
> aDT <- data.table(col1 = 1, col2 = 2, col3 = 3, col4 = 4, col5 = 5)
> aDT
   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1:    1    2    3    4    5
```

**Have tried:**

```
> setcolorder(aDT,c(index1,index2))
> aDT
   col3 col5 col1 col4 col2
1:    3    5    1    4    2
```

As you can see, it's not working. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `match`

```
setcolorder(aDT, match(seq_along(aDT), c(index1, index2)))
aDT
#   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
#1:    1    2    3    4    5
```

Comment: why i am getting error.  `object 'index1' not found`

Comment: @PIG  Have you created the object `index1` as showed in the OP's post

Comment: Yes ,I did a mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Should be using:

```
setcolorder(aDT,order(c(index1,index2)))
```

Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 2):

It's working per expectation. Look at current column order:

```
> aDT <- data.table(col5 = 5, col1 = 1, col2 = 2, col4 = 4, col3 = 3)
> aDT
   col5 col1 col2 col4 col3
1:    5    1    2    4    3
```

Now, `> setcolorder(aDT,c(index1,index2))` is suggesting to change order as `5,1,2,4,3`. Means moving current column from `5 to 1, from 1 to 2, 2 to 3 and so on`.

I think what you want can be achieved in simple lines:

```
> setcolorder(aDT,sort(names(aDT))
> aDT
   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1:    1    2    3    4    5
```

Answer (score 0):

It does exactly what you want it to do.
You provide column indices and not the colnames.
It takes the 5th column first which is called 'col3' then it takes the first one which is 'col5' and so on.
You can use the colnames by providing the colnames in the correct order you want.